# Angular Service Delete method

Tags: angular, angular-services, http-delete

I am trying to delete a customer using angular services `delete` method but I don't know how I can pass `id` parameter dynamically from the angular component. Can anyone tell me how to pass `id` dynamically?

```
deleteCustomerById(id: number): Observable<number>
      {
        const httpOptions =
        {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
        };
          return this.http.delete<number>('http://localhost:58274/api/Customers/{id}' + id, httpOptions);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for :

```
 this.http.delete<number>(`http://localhost:58274/api/Customers/${id}`, httpOptions);
```

[Details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: You dont have to add Id in httpOptions. Id is already in route.

Comment: Allah bless you